# Is there a software to convert a voice(of a specific video)to a written text(Voice-to-Text)& add it(as subtitles)to that video, simultaneously?

Tags: video, video-editing, media-converter, video-conferencing

I am an English language learner.

I encounter serious problems when watching a lot of English language videos. Some speakers talk so fast that I do not understand exactly what they are saying.

Of course, some videos on YouTube have online subtitles, but when I download them, the subtitles are not downloaded with those movies.

Therefore, this is my question:

Is there a software to **convert** a voice (voice of a particular video, talking in English) to a written text(Voice-to-Text), and also **add** this written text as subtitles to that particular video, **simultaneously**?

> As an example [this video](https://app.lecturio.com/medical-courses/neuron-.lecture)
>   has an online subtitle but when you download it, the subtitle will disappear. Any idea? (Except for using screen recorders softwares like [this](https://az-screen-recorder.en.uptodown.com/android))

NOTE: I'm not looking for sites like [Subscene](https://subscene.com/), [SubtitleSeeker](http://subtitleseeker.ee/) etc. Because I'm not actually watching movies or TV series, but I'm watching scientific videos which actually do not have any prepared subtitles and also do not exist in YouTube(So this is not a YouTube problem).

I'm using Windows and Android. Concerning the price, I'm not a child from well-off families.

**I'd appreciate your comments & suggestions!**

Comment: If you were downloading from YouTube _and a number of other sites_ I would recommend youtube-dl (https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#subtitle-options) which can fetch the subtitles (even YouTube automatic subtitles).